# How to change menu page capability

Tags: admin-menu, capabilities, user-roles, add-menu-page, add-submenu-page

Is it possible to change the capability set for a menu page, previously added with `add_menu_page()`?

I have a third plugin installed, that set a menu page created with a `'manage_options'` capability, and severals submenus with the same capability:

```
add_menu_page( $title, __( 'Menu Example','menu-example' ), 'manage_options', $page, null , $icon_url );

add_submenu_page( $parent, $title1, $title1, 'manage_options', $page1 , $function1 );
add_submenu_page( $parent, $title2, $title2, 'manage_options', $page2 , $function2 );
add_submenu_page( $parent, $title3, $title3, 'manage_options', $page3 , $function3 );
add_submenu_page( $parent, $title4, $title4, 'manage_options', $page4 , $function4 );
```

I would like in my plugin to change the capability for this parent menu and only 2 submenus, and set `my-custom-capability` for this. I need this because I have a custom rol with limit menu pages.

Comment: in the hook `admin_menu`, you can edit the menu in `$GLOBALS["menu"]`

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but only with [`add_menu_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/).

```php
/**
 * Change admin menu after add menu page
 */
function wp_nh0afl5p_admin_menu_change() {
    global $menu;

    $page_slug = 'page-slug';
    $position  = wp_nh0afl5p_search_menu_position( $page_slug );
    
    /** check position */
    if ( ! is_numeric( $position ) ) {
        return;
    }

    /** change capability */
    $menu[ $position ][1] = 'my-custom-capability';

    /** add action again */
    add_action( $menu[ $position ][5], 'page_callback' );
}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'wp_nh0afl5p_admin_menu_change', 11 );

/**
 * search submenu position
 *
 * @param $page_slug
 *
 * @return int|null
 */
function wp_nh0afl5p_search_menu_position( $page_slug ) {
    global $menu;

    foreach ( $menu as $i => $item ) {
        if ( $page_slug == $item[2] ) {
            return $i;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

It is very important that you add the page callback function again with `add_action()`. Because it is only added in the `add_menu_page()` function if `current_user_can( $capability )`, however, this is not fulfilled when the function is called.

There is a helper function that finds the menu position based on page slug.

---

It is not possible with [`add_submenu_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/). It stops at the beginning if it does not have the capability and so it doesn't add the submenu, so modification is not possible.

In this case, you have to add the submenu again with the `add_submenu_page()` function with the modified capability.